# File uploading in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, memory-management

I'm wondering in what way HttpContext.Request keeps uploaded files in memory.
Does is it hold them in RAM only or writes them in some temp dir on the HDD?
How to control this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They write the file to a temp directory. You see almost no memory use increase when uploading a file. When using this control you can't choose any other way to do it.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. Good info.